# The await operator can only be used within an async method. But i dont want to change it to async method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, http-post, azure-logic-apps

i can use "await" only within async method.So i have changed the method to async as shown below.

public async Task Add_recordAsync(register rs) { }.

but i dont want to change it to async method.is there any alternative?please help.

Here is my code:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

> i dont want to change it to async method.

You have to use `async` in order to use `await`. Changing your code to `async` is the cleanest and most performant solution.

> is there any alternative?

[Yes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2015/july/async-programming-brownfield-async-development). But every approach has drawbacks. There is no alternative approach that works in every situation.

At the end of the day, it's best to either go `async` all the way or keep it synchronous all the way. Mixing the two always causes pain.

Comment: Hi Stephen, i have changed my method to async . but i cant hit the logic app url, following  is my code. HttpResponseMessage result = await client.PostAsync(          
            ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Logic app URL"],
            new StringContent(jsonData, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
           
            var statusCode = result.StatusCode.ToString();

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "i cant hit the logic app url"

Comment: I mean calling/triggering logic app url from MVC application.

Answer (score 0):

Now i'm able to call / trigger logic app url from MVC application. And i could able to pass json data  to logic app url . Following is  my code.

[image]
[![enter image description here][image: []]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EPUox.png)

Reference : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/tutorial-send-email?tabs=dotnet#more-resources